# Underscore chaining inner workings

Tags: javascript, closures, underscore.js

I'm, curios how the `_.chain`ing [function is implemented](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-139) and how (or better, why) it works the way it does.

Especially my question is where does the wrapping for each function happen. Let's assume I'm using `_.chain(someArray).filter(...);` When I step into the function, I can see that the filter function got transformed into something like

```
function () { 
     var args = [this._wrapped]; //the data from chain(...)
     push.apply(args, arguments); //push to the (?) array
     return result.call(this, func.apply(_, args)); //?? where are these coming from?
}
```

I can see that the function has 3 Closures in it's scope (compare this to the [un-chained function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LR0Jf.png) that show the definition of the function without all the Closure to it's original function)

[image: scope after using the chain function]

The first one is the [find function](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-17) itself, the second ["the safe reference to the object itself"](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-9) and the third on the underscore class itself.

When calling `_.chain()`, how and where (code-wise) does the transformation (the creating of the scopes etc). I can see that

```
//http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-139
 _.chain = function(obj) {
    return _(obj).chain();
  };
```

gets called and this goes to

```
//http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-145
//...
 chain: function() {
      this._chain = true;
      return this;
    },
//...
```

Then I'm stuck. I can't figure out what happens from there. I assume that the magic happens inside the [constructor](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-9), but I can't seem to figure out where the additional creation of the Closures comes in. All the functions themselves don't show any sign of being wrapped, the chain call doesn't look like it wraps something. `result` seems to be there but I don't know where it came from. So, where and how does this happen?

Comment: http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-143 right at the end, you can see where all the prototype methods are added

Answer (score 0):

`_.chain(obj)` returns new instance of `_` with attribute `_chain = true`, that instance of `_` has a `_wrapped` attribute set to current object (great work here). `_.mixin(_)` in line `#1210` add all of underscore methods to underscore (constructor). `_.mixin` method replace and extend `_` methods (still has the parent functions! Accessible via `_.prototype`). `_.mixin` change functions of that `_` instance (this is the place you see that new function).

New function is:

```
function () {
  var args = [this._wrapped];
  push.apply(args, arguments);
  return result.call(this, func.apply(_, args));
}
```

<sup>(doesn't matter what method it is, same for all, func is referenced to the original method)</sup>

`result` method function is :

```
var result = function(obj) {
  return this._chain ? _(obj).chain() : obj;
};
```

so if the object returned by `func.apply(_, args)` has `_chain` (`_.chain` set that attribute) returns `_(obj).chain()` then you can use it again :)

This is process of chaining but what about prototypes!

In constructor function :

```
var _ = function(obj) {
  if (obj instanceof _) return obj;
  if (!(this instanceof _)) return new _(obj); // This line do the magic
  this._wrapped = obj;
};
```

Consider this :

```
func = function(a){this.a = a;}
b = func(2);
b.a // TypeError: Cannot read property 'a' of undefined
c = new func(2);
c.a // returns 2, whooa this the magical javascript!
```

Read this ([Underscore docs about OOP](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-140)) if you want to learn more about underscore mixin function

Am I missing something?